# XGBoost feature_names mismatch time series

Tags: python, time-series, xgboost, stock

I am trying to predict the stock trend where 1 is the stock increases and 0 is the stock decreases on that particular day. My input features are close price, volume, current  day trend and my output is the trend the next day. When applying XGBClassifier() I encounter an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-d14cdb520e55> in <module>
      1 val = np.array(test[0, 0]).reshape(1, -1)
      2 
----> 3 pred = model.predict(val)
      4 print(pred[0])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py in predict(self, data, output_margin, ntree_limit, validate_features, base_margin)
    968         if ntree_limit is None:
    969             ntree_limit = getattr(self, "best_ntree_limit", 0)
--> 970         class_probs = self.get_booster().predict(
    971             test_dmatrix,
    972             output_margin=output_margin,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in predict(self, data, output_margin, ntree_limit, pred_leaf, pred_contribs, approx_contribs, pred_interactions, validate_features, training)
   1483 
   1484         if validate_features:
-> 1485             self._validate_features(data)
   1486 
   1487         length = c_bst_ulong()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in _validate_features(self, data)
   2058                             ', '.join(str(s) for s in my_missing))
   2059 
-> 2060                 raise ValueError(msg.format(self.feature_names,
   2061                                             data.feature_names))
   2062 

ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'] ['f0']
expected f2, f1, f3 in input data
```

My code is as follows:

```
def xgb_predict(train, val):
    train = np.array(train)
    x, y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1] 
    model = XGBClassifier()
    model.fit(x, y)
    
    val = np.array(val).reshape(1, -1)
    pred = model.predict(val)
    return pred[0]

xgb_predict(train, test[0, 0])
```

I receive an error on the 8th line. Thank you very much for the help:)

Edit: [Included a sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZaVa.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just from what you posted I would say that you need to select more columns from your test data. To make sure that this is the case, could you please edit your question to add a sample of your data? My guess would be to change the last line to `xgb_predict(train, test[0, :])`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the welcome! I have changed my last line as you said but the error now says "training data did not have the following fields: f3". Thank you for the help

Comment: Makes sense, since the last column is the target one. I've posted an answer. Check it out, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column selection of your test data must be done as you do for the train data. This means that your last line should be:

```
xgb_predict(train, test[0, :-1])
```

so you can select all columns/features but the last one which is the target value.

Comment: Thank you so much it has worked! Can you clarify why it should be [:-1] instead of [0] please? Is it because in my original I was only selecting 1 column whereas I needed to select 4 to match my training data?

Comment: Note that you split your training data into `x` and `y`. The `x` contains the independent variables, your features. The `y` contain the target value, the ground truth. For the training phase, you use both so the model can learn the patterns in your data. For the testing phase, we only use the features (all columns but the last one from your original data, like the `x` of the training data) for the model to make a prediction. The target value of your test data is only used to check how well your model performed.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand how to know how to match feature names. e.g How would I know next time to put [:-1] instead of [0]?

Comment: You don't need to know the feature names. Those feature names are created by the xgboost itself. For the testing, you just need to select the same features that you used in the training. In other words, the same slice that you do in the second dimension while training (the `:-1` part in `train[:, :-1]`) must be done when testing (`test[0, :-1]`)